# Create folder move files - Applescript

Tags: file, makefile, applescript, directory

I'm looking to:

1. Move folder from desktop

   1a. Create a folder with **set jobName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter Job Name:" default answer "Job_Name")**

   1b. Drop folder from desktop inside the **make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"Emails"}**

Script:

```
set jobName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter Job Name:" default     answer "Job_Name")
set loc to choose folder "Choose Parent Folder Location"

tell application "Finder"
set home_path to home as text
set source to alias (home_path & "Desktop:WorkingFolder")
set newfo to make new folder at loc with properties {name:jobName}
    make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"Emails"}

set destination to home_path & jobName

tell application "Finder" to duplicate source to destination with replacing
end tell
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
    set jobName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter Job Name:" default answer "Job_Name")
set loc to choose folder with prompt "Choose Parent Folder Location"

tell application "Finder"
    set source to alias ((path to desktop as text) & "WorkingFolder:")
    set newfo to make new folder at loc with properties {name:jobName}
    make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"Emails"}
    set destination to make new folder at (path to home folder) with properties {name:jobName}
    tell application "Finder" to duplicate source to destination with replacing
end tell
```

Comment: YES! Pretty much.. Looking to have the "Screenshots" folder inside the root directory..So not adding it to the folder I create, but the content inside the, "Screenshots" folder. @craigsmith

Comment: I was wondering why you were using the home directory.  Sorry about leaving the **Screenshots** term in there.  Please see if the edited script is closer.

Comment: You are welcome.  Do you mind please marking this as the answer?